# Make variation stock quantity appear on dropdown selection in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

Currently this is what it shows in our site with the current code:
[image]

The current code shows all the stocks before even clicking on any of the variation/sizes. What our client wants is to only show that specific variation's stock quantity once they are clicked/selected on the drop down.
Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Current Code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'display_stock_variations_loop' );
function display_stock_variations_loop(){
    global $product;
    if ( $product->get_type() == 'variable' ) {
        foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $key ) {
            $attr_string = array();
            foreach ( $key['attributes'] as $attr_name => $attr_value ) {
                $attr_string[] = $attr_value;
            }
            if ( $key['max_qty'] > 0 ) { 
        echo '' . implode( ', ', $attr_string ) . ': ' . $key['max_qty'] . ' in stock<br>'; 
            } else { 
        echo '' . implode(', ', $attr_string ) . ': out of stock<br>'; 
            }
    }
    echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to manage it via javascript / jquery on variation dropdown change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The displayed selected variation stock quantity and status **is already managed by woocommerce**. You just need to add your "Size" attribute term name value, using the following *(without any javascript need)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'filter_variations_availability_text', 10, 2 );
function filter_variations_availability_text( $availability_text, $product ) {

    if( $product->get_type() == 'variation' && $product->get_attribute('size') ) {

        $availability_text = $product->get_attribute('size') . ': ' . $availability_text;
    }
    return $availability_text;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

[image]